# Django, REST. Создание сериалайзера с многократной вложенностью

Tags: django, rest, serialize, django-rest-framework

Имеются две модели со связью one-to-many, прямо как [доках](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#api-reference)

```js
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=GENRE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('album', 'order')
        ordering = ['order']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%d: %s' % (self.order, self.title)
```

`django-rest-framework` позволяет учитывать эту связь

```js
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('order', 'title', 'duration')

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

и создавать вложенные структуры, с которыми можно работать как на чтение, так и на запись

```js
{
    'album_name': 'The Grey Album',
    'artist': 'Danger Mouse',
    'tracks': [
        {'order': 1, 'title': 'Public Service Announcement', 'duration': 245},
        {'order': 2, 'title': 'What More Can I Say', 'duration': 264},
        {'order': 3, 'title': 'Encore', 'duration': 159},
        ...
    ],
}
```

А можно создавать структуры с дополнтительно вложенностью, например, учитывать разбиение по полю жанра `genre`?

```js
{
    'album_name': 'The Grey Album',
    'artist': 'Danger Mouse',
    'tracks': [
      {
      'rock': [
        {'order': 1, 'title': 'Public Service Announcement', 'duration': 245},
        {'order': 2, 'title': 'What More Can I Say', 'duration': 264},
        {'order': 3, 'title': 'Encore', 'duration': 159}],

      'classic': [
        {'order': 1, 'title': 'Public Service Announcement', 'duration': 245},
        {'order': 2, 'title': 'What More Can I Say', 'duration': 264},
        {'order': 3, 'title': 'Encore', 'duration': 159}]

        ...
      }
    ],
}
```

Знаю, что могу использовать для `properties` [SerializerMethodField()](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) и получить любую структуру, но этот способ создает только read-only поля без возможности изменения.

Какие еще способы есть решить проблему?

Comment: Напишите свой serializer, в котором вручную собирайте и разбирайте данные. Посмотрите как реализован класс ModelSerializer и чем он отличается от класса Serializer. Потом создайте свой класс, отнаследованный от Serailizer.

Comment: Да, я уже сейчас переписываю api с кастомными сериалайзером, modelserializer слишком "негибкие"